# Dual-Boot Problems

Tags: dual-boot, windows-10

I'm having a really bad problem. I can't dual-boot Windows 10 with Ubuntu.
I know the fdisk comand but it says it gonna to delete some sort of system files. I don't know at all what i have to do!
I really need help and fast as possible!

Thank You!

Comment: Is Windows 10 from Windows 7 (prob BIOS)or 8 or original install (UEFI)?  Only if Ubuntu is installed in same boot mode as Windows, will `sudo update-grub` work. Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info

Comment: I think it's intalled on a BIOS PHOENIX. But i will probably install Ubuntu 16.04 and then i will dual boot windows 10 with the /boot Partition. Thank You!

Comment: If standard desktop better not to use /boot partition unless you want full drive encryption which requires the /boot partition and full drive install also erases Windows. Separate /home and/or shared NTFS partition may make more sense.